# Emacs as git editor does not load COMMIT_EDITMSG

Tags: git, emacs

I am using git (on linux) and want to use emacs as editor. However after `git config --global core.editor emacs` any git commit open emacs in *scratch* buffer and does not load COMMIT_EDITMSG at all.

How to force them to work with each other? So git commit will open emacs editor with  COMMIT_EDITMSG loaded?

Comment: Are there any error messages in your `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: no errors, I guess there is some setting must be to send .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG to emacs, and I miss it.

Comment: COMMIT_EDITMSG is just a file in `.git` directory. All that Git does is tells Emacs to start up with loading that file. Things to check: 1. maybe `emacs` in your environment is an alias for `emacs` with some options. 2. Try `emacs -nw` instead (maybe opening it in window server causes some problems). 3. try simply executing `emacs ./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` 4. If you are already running one copy of Emacs at that time: read on `emacsclient`. 5. Why not use `magit` or `vc-git`?

Comment: 'emacs .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG' open scratch also (I think we are close). I do not write the code in emacs, so do not need magit I guess.

Comment: root is owner of .emacs.d, add you comments as answer, I'll accept it :) All I need to do is `sudo chown -hR logcat:logcat .emacs.d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `emacs ./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` had the same behavior (*scratch* buffer was opened). That's because owner of `.emacs.d` folder was root. All I need to do is simply change the owner `sudo chown -hR logcat:logcat .emacs.d/`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, you don't have to touch ~/.gitconfig to change the editor.
You can just

```
export VISUAL=emacsclient
```

To make this change permanent, add this line to ~/.bashrc.

Comment: the pretty same thing, when I try to commit, emacs open scratch, but not the commit_editmsg

Comment: did you undo your changes to ~/.gitconfig?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer that is displayed on startup is controlled by the variable `initial-buffer-choice`. In your `.emacs` file set it to `nil`:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; ...other variables might be set here
 '(initial-buffer-choice nil))
```

If you call emacs with `emacs <filename>` it will now display the file instead of the scratch buffer on startup. This also holds for `COMMIT_EDITMSG`. If you don't pass a filenam to emacs it will display the scratch buffer.

You might also want to disable the splash screen to be dipslayed in a split screen. To do this add the following line to your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
```